# Timer.Elapsed and BeginInvoke still lag GUI

Tags: c#, wpf, timer, dispatcher

There is a piece of 3rd party API code, `SomeWork()`, that needs to run every 3 seconds to monitor some physical devices. I would of thought using using System.Timers.Timer and its Elapse event is asynchronous, but it lags my GUI operation every 3 seconds. I tried doing `SomeWork()` using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke yet I still experience the same lag on the GUI, even `SomeWork()` does not actually update any GUI and should not occupy the GUI thread.

```
private void StartTimerAtStartup()
{
    System.Timers.Timer connTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    connTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(MyTimer_Elapsed);
    connTimer.Interval = 3000; 
    connTimer.Enabled = true;
}

private void MyTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, (ElapsedEventHandler)MyTimer_Elapsed, sender, e);
        return;
    }

    // Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(
    //             () => SomeWork())
    // );

    SomeWork();
}
```

**[EDIT1]**

If I remove all Dispatcher and call SomeWork() directly then I get an exception that I cannot access this thread.

**[EDIT2]**

SomeWork() is a 3rd party API listening to physical devices and receiving packets, which does not touch the GUI. I tried various ways of doing the Dispatcher.BeginInvoke and I encounter the following, which I cannot understand. Why would using lamda lags the GUI but doing a delegate does not lag the GUI?

```
// This lags the GUI
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action( () => SomeWork() ));

// This does not lag the GUI. Application runs smooth, 
// but I do not understand why
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate () { SomeWork(); });
```

Comment: remove all dispatcher thing. and only call `SomeWork();`. will it still lag?

Comment: Per your Edit, you must be doing something that touches the UI. Update your question with the code throwing the error.

Comment: Try using DispatcherTimer.

Comment: @sthotakura, I have also tried DispatcherTime, same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call Dispatcher of GUI thread. Thus, BeginInvoke invokes async work to UI thread and you get your UI lagged.
Your timer fires `Elapsed` event in the different than UI thread. So you can just simply call your method in the event handler.

However, if you need to call your API strictly every 3 seconds than you need to either consider time that takes to execute SomeWork or do the job in separated thread. Then you can use tasks to achieve that.

```
 Task.Factory.StartNew(SomeWork);
```

But in this case you will have to deal with possible race conditions and synchronize your work.